# insertion of wrong values in database

Tags: android, sql, database

i had created two activities to take data from the user, the data from the first activity is carried to the second activity and then together the data of first activity and second activity is stored in the database. the data of the second activity is perfect in db but the data of the first activity is wrong. this is my code.

```
dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        String course=dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
        edit_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        edit_email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        edit_pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        edit_conpass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String name1=edit_name.getText().toString();
        String email1=edit_email.getText().toString();
        String pas=edit_pass.getText().toString();
        String conpass=edit_conpass.getText().toString();
        if(pas.equals(conpass))
        {
            edit_name.setText(" ");
            edit_email.setText(" ");
            edit_pass.setText(" ");
            edit_conpass.setText(" ");
        Intent fin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                Form.class);
        fin.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name1);
        fin.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, email1);
        fin.putExtra(TAG_PASS, pas);
        fin.putExtra(TAG_COURSE, course);

        startActivity(fin);
```

and my second activity is.

```
 public class Form extends Activity {

protected static final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 0;
private static final String TAG_NAME = null;
private static final String TAG_PASS = null;
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = null;
private static final String TAG_COURSE = null;
SQLiteDatabase db=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);
    getIntent();
     db= openOrCreateDatabase("Angel", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
       db.execSQL("create table if not exists login1(name varchar,email varchar,age integer,course varchar,phone integer,password varchar)");


    Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    NumberPicker numpic=(NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
    numpic.setMaxValue(99);
    numpic.setMinValue(0);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
     startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE); 
        }
    });


    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent fin=getIntent();
            EditText editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String username=fin.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
            String email=fin.getStringExtra(TAG_EMAIL);
            String password=fin.getStringExtra(TAG_PASS);

             String course=fin.getStringExtra(TAG_COURSE);
             String no=editText1.getText().toString();
                long no2=Long.parseLong(no);  
                NumberPicker numpic=(NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
                int a=numpic.getValue();
            db.execSQL("insert into login1 values('"+username+"','"+email+"','"+a+"','"+course+"','"+no2+"','"+password+"')");
            db.close();
            Toast.makeText(Form.this, "values inserted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}
}
```

i am not storing the image as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...........

```
public class Form extends Activity 
{
protected static final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 0;
SQLiteDatabase db=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);
    getIntent();
     db= openOrCreateDatabase("Angel", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
       db.execSQL("create table if not exists login1(name varchar,email varchar,age integer,course varchar,phone integer,password varchar)");


    Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    NumberPicker numpic=(NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
    numpic.setMaxValue(99);
    numpic.setMinValue(0);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
     startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE); 
        }
    });


    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent fin=getIntent();
            EditText editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String username=fin.getStringExtra("TAG_NAME");
            String email=fin.getStringExtra("TAG_EMAIL");
            String password=fin.getStringExtra("TAG_PASS");
             String course=fin.getStringExtra("TAG_COURSE");
             String no=editText1.getText().toString();
                long no2=Long.parseLong(no);  
                NumberPicker numpic=(NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
                int a=numpic.getValue();
            db.execSQL("insert into login1 values('"+username+"','"+email+"','"+a+"','"+course+"','"+no2+"','"+password+"')");
            db.close();
            Toast.makeText(Form.this, "values inserted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your `Strings` like so..

```
private static final String TAG_NAME = "TAG";
private static final String TAG_PASS = "PASS";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "EMAIL";
private static final String TAG_COURSE = "COURSE";
```

These are your Unique Identifier Strings and it's not null.

### Update:

Another way is

```
 Intent fin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            Form.class);
    fin.putExtra("TAG", name1);
    fin.putExtra("EMAIL", email1);
    fin.putExtra("PASS", pas);
    fin.putExtra("COURSE", course);
```

and get it like

```
   Intent fin=getIntent().getExtras();
   String username=fin.getStringExtra("TAG");
   String email=fin.getStringExtra("EMAIL");
   String password=fin.getStringExtra("PASS");
   String course=fin.getStringExtra("COURSE");
```

Comment: @user3782868 You need to initialize  this Unique Identifier string in your Both Activity....